# How to deal with answers which are just a solution in some cases?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I just had this answer in the review: [How to run a shell script at startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973777/how-to-run-a-shell-script-at-startup/27172425#27172425)

And I wasn't sure how to deal with it?

I felt like I had to flag it, as Answers should answer the Question over all named cases. And not only serve a solution for some supposed given conditions, which aren't named by the OP.

But The given Flag options at all also didn't feel right. Flagging it as Not an answer also didn't feel right. As it is a answer. But a answer what would not help everyone in this situation.

So is this kind of answer ok?

Or how would I have to handle it?

Comment: If it's not blatantly wrong, you could choose not to upvote. I don't think it needs any other action than that.

Comment: I could give you an answer for your question, but it would only be valid for your specific case.

Comment: @Renan And what is the problem with that? If you try to make fun about me, read my question exactly. I said, the answer is just answering a specific case which is which is not given by the op. ie. a answer for a specific OS, whilest the OP is asking for a solution OS independed (By just not mentioning any OS) Got it?

Comment: I am not a shellscript expert but I think that piece of code in the answer you mentioned would work not only in any Linux setup but also in mostly any other Unix based OS.

Comment: @Renan The OS thing was an example to calrify what my meta question is about. The question is about answers that solve the OP problem, but only if some circumstances are given which arent considered by OP. So yeah, it could satisfy the asking one. But others who may have the same problem as op but different cicumstances may not be satisfied by the answer even if they could describe their problem in exactly the same words as the OP did. That is what my question is about. Because this would lead to flaging duplicates of posts where is no usefull answer in vie of the dulicate post.

Comment: @Zaibis The problem you are presenting in your question lies squarely into the gray area where people's opinions are going to differ. Most people are going to agree that the answer is not worthy of a being flagged. However, does it merit a downvote, no vote, or an upvote? That's really up to what your standards are. Some people upvote answers that contain true statements, no matter how removed from the question these true statements may be. Vote according to what your standards are.

Comment: @Renan The answer works if you have a desktop environment that presents an interface that has an option (presumably a menu somewhere) that goes `System > Preferences > Startup Applications`. The question however is about how to get `init.d` to run a script at startup. The answer that Zaibis pointed out does not answer *this question.* This does not make the answer NAA, but it does make it a terrible answer.

Answer (score 3):

That's known as a partial answer, and thus an attempt at answering.

Even though it is not complete, at worst it deserves a downvote, and probably not even that.

As to review, the proper action would be *optionally* prompting the poster to complete it with a comment (if nobody already did,providing a hint at what's missing), and selecting "No action needed".